# bluetooth le gatt client and server

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been trying to get an android ble gatt client to talk to an android ble gatt server.

I have been following the example discussed at this blog:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-part-1/

The source code for the blog is here:

https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-bluetooth-testbed

The sample app can act as a gatt client or server. When I start the server, it correctly advertises the peripheral and the client scans and find the server. When I press "connect", the onCharacteristicReadRequest of the GattServerCallback is called and it attempts to send a response back to the client on line 52 of GattServerCallback.java:

https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-bluetooth-testbed/blob/master/BluetoothLowEnergy/app/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/android/bluetoothtestbed/server/GattServerCallback.java

This calls fails with a null pointer error:

```
17 14:44:43.358 17888-17925/com.bignerdranch.android.bluetoothlowenergy W/BluetoothGattServer: Unhandled exception in callback
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1699)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.sendResponse(IBluetoothGatt.java:1424)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(BluetoothGattServer.java:599)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.bluetoothtestbed.server.ServerActivity.sendResponse(ServerActivity.java:315)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.bluetoothtestbed.server.GattServerCallback.onDescriptorWriteRequest(GattServerCallback.java:115)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServer$1.onDescriptorWriteRequest(BluetoothGattServer.java:261)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattServerCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattServerCallback.java:263)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Following the exception, the client disconnects and the `onConnectionStateChange` method is called and the client device is removed on lines 34 to 36:

```
else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
        mServerActionListener.removeDevice(device);
}
```

No further communication between the client and server is possible. On the client there is a text box which allows you to send a message to the server but no message gets through to the server presumably because of the disconnect.

I have put together an example which generates the same exception up on github at [ble-echo](https://github.com/jmc420/ble-echo).

Can anyone explain why this example does not work?